# Rails app deployed "successfully" to Heroku but returns application error, does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github

I pushed my Rails App to Heroku and it said "successfully installed" but when I try to open it says:

"Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

This is my repo: https://github.com/cyqurayte/Rails1
I don't understand the errors in the log(at the very bottom of the log), can you help me? I tried it twice, but returns the same.

```html
2017-09-02T16:52:14.366977+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2017-09-02T16:52:14.366997+00:00 app[web.1]:  from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-09-02T16:52:14.366998+00:00 app[web.1]:  from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-09-02T16:52:14.418105+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-09-02T16:52:14.418107+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:31449
2017-09-02T16:52:14.418108+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-09-02T16:52:14.418109+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-09-02T16:52:14.568245+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-09-02T16:52:14.570537+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-09-02T16:52:17.689558+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 16636 -e production`
2017-09-02T16:52:21.271268+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159151+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159165+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:185:in `spec'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159166+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159167+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159167+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159168+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159168+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `execute_hook'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159169+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159171+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159172+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159172+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159173+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159173+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/app/models/application_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159174+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159174+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159174+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159175+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159175+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:379:in `block in require_or_load'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159176+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `block in load_interlock'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159176+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159176+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159177+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159178+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `load_interlock'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159179+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:357:in `require_or_load'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159196+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:335:in `depend_on'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159197+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require_dependency'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159198+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159213+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159214+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159215+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159216+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159227+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159227+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `each'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159229+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159229+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159230+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159231+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159232+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159234+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159235+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159247+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159247+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159248+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159248+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159250+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159250+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159251+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159252+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159255+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159254+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159256+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159268+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159268+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159269+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:in `new'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159270+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159270+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:in `<main>'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159272+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159273+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159274+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159275+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159288+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159276+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159289+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159288+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159290+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:131:in `block in perform'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159290+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `tap'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159292+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `perform'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159294+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159293+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159295+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159298+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159296+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159308+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159309+00:00 app[web.1]:  from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.159309+00:00 app[web.1]:  from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-09-02T16:52:21.189355+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-09-02T16:52:21.189358+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-09-02T16:52:21.189358+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:16636
2017-09-02T16:52:21.189359+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-09-02T16:52:21.285641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-09-02T16:52:43.214143+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate` by user cherian.grundmann@gmail.com
2017-09-02T16:52:46.963608+00:00 heroku[run.8994]: Awaiting client
2017-09-02T16:52:47.023608+00:00 heroku[run.8994]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate`
2017-09-02T16:52:47.075762+00:00 heroku[run.8994]: State changed from starting to up
2017-09-02T16:52:54.615275+00:00 heroku[run.8994]: Process exited with status 1
2017-09-02T16:52:54.628832+00:00 heroku[run.8994]: State changed from up to complete
2017-09-02T16:53:04.473474+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-depths-56542.herokuapp.com request_id=10fdf26d-2a66-4472-87e6-ece56707f399 fwd="95.91.246.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-02T16:53:04.837571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-depths-56542.herokuapp.com request_id=13f1eb53-b357-4b0b-8a8b-05f20067caa2 fwd="95.91.246.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-02T16:56:34.250511+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-depths-56542.herokuapp.com request_id=8bb799bb-6c2b-4e0f-a470-e7967ff108ef fwd="95.91.246.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-02T16:56:34.727244+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-depths-56542.herokuapp.com request_id=77dad4f7-5a2f-4ee7-9177-3bf50127ffbb fwd="95.91.246.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

?

Comment: Is it working now?

Answer (score 1):

The log in heroku doesn't always give enough details you could have a missing file or an error that you have accounted for like a variable et cetera. When you troubleshoot before you launched did you make sure all errors were taken care of? Try `heroku run rails console` might be able to give you more insight as to what your issue may be. Or try `heroku restart` and follow the console errors.

Comment: There is this error in the heroku console:
"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
"
But I do have
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
"
in my gem and "gem 'sqlite3' only in the development group, also tried to comment the latter out, but either way it does not work.

Comment: ok, now it worked after I added gem 'pg' to the default group as well. Does this has something to do with this? I want to understand...
"No Procfile detected, using the default web server."

Comment: Do you know if you are using puma?

Comment: Can you also find your Procfile and show what it has in it

Comment: NVM I see you are using puma

Comment: No idea what puma and where my Procfile is.

Comment: You should use a text editor like sublime and you can just search for the Procfile file in your app.

Comment: There is none. "Searching 430 files for "procfile"

0 matches"

Comment: Wait, I have "gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'" in my gemfile.
Procfile seems not to exist.
Also meanwhile my bug search has progressed. Heroku deploy only installs pg when pg is part of the default group in my gemfile. But in that case 'install bundle' returns. 
"An error occurred while installing pg (0.21.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.21.0'` succeeds before bundling."

My database.yml goes for sqlite3 in case of default.

Comment: Fix your database.yml make sure pg is default everything remove any reference to sqlite.

Comment: Thanks @JermaineSubia your suggestion "heroku run rails console" has helped me fixing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs it would seem your application is failing to connect to your database. This is pointed out by the fact that it specifies in the error that your missing the postgres gem, add `gem 'pg'` to your gemfile or confirm your database.yml is setup correctly.

Comment: I had added it. But not sure what you mean by database.yml, I started with Ruby the before yesterday, with Rails yesterday and Heroku today...

But my site works now, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs it would seem your application is failing to connect to your database. This is pointed out by the fact that it's ActiveRecord complaining about the

Answer (score 0):

This is my database.yml

```html
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: pg
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: Your db's are pointing to an sql lite database which won't work on Heroku.